# Show main TabBar for an item which is not a TabBar Item, but is in Menu(Using SWRevealCotroller)

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWRevealViewController` for side menu.
and also I have a tabbar controller as main view in my app.

In my menu I have "`MenuItem`" (which presents `MenuItemViewController`) and the tab bar items are "`TabItem1`" and "`TabItem2`".

Here is what I need:

1. Show the tab bar in "`MenuItemViewController`".
2. To have back button(bar button) that goes back to the `TabItem1ViewController`.
3. I do not want to have a new item for "`MenuItem`" in my tabbar.

[What I Have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSTYi.png)

[What I Need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4qJ0.png)

BTW, the top left view controller is the side menu.

Comment: what is your exact question or problem ?

Comment: @arash The tabbar is not added when presenting a viewController when an item inside the side menu is clicked.

Comment: To show the `UITabBar` when presenting a viewController, one way is presenting your viewController from tabBar's controller.

Comment: @MRFrhn Unfortunately The design forces me to show tabbar in sideBar items, without adding them to the tabbar.

Answer (score 0):

I have something that i think will match your requirement, or maybe you'll get an idea from this.

[image: Example from one of my works.]

What's happening here is a tab bar with any number of view is embedded inside a navigation bar. and the menu screen is the rear view of swrevealView and navigation bar is the front view. Ask if you have any doubt.

Comment: So, the main problem is about side bar items. I know about using swreveal menu, and also about using tabbar controller. The question is that how can I show the tabbar in a view controller which load from a side bar menu?

Comment: You want to open the tab bar when you click on a menu item?

Comment: Yes, but when the menu item is not a tabbar item!

Comment: then you can create a segue from the table menu to the view in which you want to embed the tab bar..
give it an identifier and inside didSelectRow method of table view, just perform that segue. The menu will now be shown in that view.

Comment: I have added two images. I think it helps to make my problem more clear.

Comment: @MarjanBSR It is actually more confusing. I'll remove my answer if it is not relevant.

Comment: Ooom... Just careful about the tabbar items, I do not want to have a menu item in my tabbar buttons (and I have tested your solution before, unfortunately it does not work correctly.)

Comment: All right, keep trying you'll be able to do it. I'll leave the answer in case it might help someone else.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ashish Sharma ^_^